# Ver quais elementos da lista são primos

Tags: python-3.x, lista

Olá, estou fazendo uma lista de exercícios e me deparei com uma questão que consiste em ler os elementos de uma lista e determinar quantos são primos.

Eu só consegui fazer a função pra calcular os números primos, mas não sei fazer pra lista inteira, alguém pode me ajudar?

```
def primos(x)
    entrada = int(input())
    contadora = 1
    divisores = 0

    while contadora <= entrada:
        if entrada%contadora==0:
            divisores += 1
            contadora += 1
        else:
            contadora += 1
    if divisores != 2:
        print ('nao eh primo')
    elif divisores == 2:
        print ('eh primo')
```

Eu penso que uma solução seria ler a lista por parâmetro em uma função 2 e chamar a função "primos" para cada elemento da lista da função 2 (lista[i]), mas não sei como escrever isso...

Answer (score -1):

A função utilizada para verificar se um número é primo nesta resposta baseia-se na [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15285588/10876117) de [dawg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298607/dawg) no [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/). Esta função é muito mais eficiente porque só é necessário verificar até à raiz quadrada de `n` para sabermos se `n` é primo. Existem outras formas de implementar esta função, umas mais eficientes que outras, esta funciona à "força bruta" pelo que só estamos a verificar até à raiz quadrada do número.

Depois de termos uma função que verifique se um dado números é primo, neste caso, `verificar_primo(n)`, só temos de contar o número de vezes que os elementos da sua lista são primos:

```py
def verificar_primo(n): # admitindo que n é natural
  if n == 2 or n == 3: return True
  if n < 2 or n%2 == 0: return False
  if n < 9: return True
  if n%3 == 0: return False
  r = int(n**0.5)
  f = 5
  while f <= r:
    if n%f == 0: return False
    if n%(f+2) == 0: return False
    f += 6
  return True    

a_sua_lista=list(range(1,
contador=0
for i in a_sua_lista:
  if i==int(i) and i>0 and verificar_primo(i): # se i for natural e primo, se tivermos a certeza que i é natural basta escrever: if verificar_primo(i):
    contador+=1

print("Existem %d elementos primos nesta lista." % contador)
```

Output:

```
Existem 5 elementos primos nesta lista.
```